# Update database where duplicate field exists using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple php file that adds an id and time to a database. How can I alter it to  only update 'time' if the 'id' is the same as an id already in the database and to add both as usual if the id is not in the database already? I have come across the 'INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' syntax but can't quite implement it correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="*****";
$password="*****";
$db_name="*****";

$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
$time = intval(htmlspecialchars($_GET["time"]));

echo $id;
echo $time;

$data = array("id" => $id, "time" => $time);

var_dump($data);

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO testdata (id, time) VALUES (?, ?)");

if($stmt === FALSE)
    die("Prepare failed... ");// Handle Error Here

    // the types of the data we are about to insert: s = string, i = int
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $data['id'], $data['time']);    
    $stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

// close the connection to the database
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: `'INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'` is the way to go. You need to make sure your `id` is either a `PRIMARY KEY`, or is marked `UNIQUE`. If you can't make it work update your question with some details on what is happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
INSERT INTO testdata (id,time) VALUES(?,?) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=values(time)
```

But as @Mike W said in the comment, make sure ID is either a Primary Key or Unique INDEX. More information in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks Filipe, I was annoyingly close but your suggestion worked perfectly once I made id a primary key! Cheers.